# A wifi and mobile data testing app.

Tags: android, wifi, diagnostics

I've been having a bit of difficulty with my phone recently, and I'm wanting to diagnose whether it's the phone that has a problem, or perhaps just the wifi/mobile network.

What I'd like is an application that will periodically, say over a two hour period, perform internet connectivity tests, and then provide some kind of feedback at the end of it.

I could then use this application accross two devices to check whether it's the phone or the network.

Comment: You can find a bunch of diagnostic apps in my [Network Diagnosis app-list](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_diagnosis). I don't know which of those would be a "perfect match" for your case, but that overview should definitely help you narrowing down your search.

Answer (score 5):

Based on [Hueys answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/20688/185), here's an approach easier to use for you – and coming closer to what you're after. There's an app called **[Ping & DNS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ulfdittmer.android.ping)** offering several network tools which, on a `ping`, even can display a graphical analysis:

[image: Ping & DNS] [image: Ping & DNS]
<sup>*Ping & DNS* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ulfdittmer.android.ping); click images for larger variants)</sup>

I have not used this app myself, so I cannot give any verdict on it. But quoting from the app's description, it should be pretty much what you're after:

> The results can be copied (via long-click on the output text), sent via email or stored in a file as text or PDF. A history of the results of recent operations is kept (swipe left and right to switch between tabs).
>
> Numerous options (like using an alternative name server, Ping TTL, showing ping times for each traceroute step, Broadcast Ping, using HTTPS, setting the HTTP port number, selection of DNS record types to query, etc.) are available through a long-click on the "Go" button.

The dev promises it "Contains no ads", it's [available at Google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ulfdittmer.android.ping) at no cost, and has a pretty good ranking (4.3 stars at over 5k votes), so it's at least worth a try!

For more alternatives, you're welcome checking my relevant app lists:

- [Toolboxes: Ping, WhoIs, etc](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_info#group_383)
- [Network Diagnosis](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_diagnosis)
- and more :)

Answer (score 3):

You could try `ping` for a minimalistic solution.

> Ping is a computer network administration software utility used to test the reachability of a host on an Internet Protocol (IP) network and to measure the round-trip time for messages sent from the originating host to a destination computer and back.

On Windows, you can do something like

```
ping www.google.com -t
```

to continuously ping. On Unix systems it's just

```
ping www.google.com
```

[image: ping output]

You can check your `ttl`, how long the packet takes to be transmitted, etc. This can provide an indication as to the reliability of your network connection.

On Android, with a [terminal emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm), you can ping as well.

Comment: CLI tools are hard to use on small-size screens (think of a 4" display), there are graphical alternatives for `ping` that are much more "natural" to use, see e.g. my list [Toolboxes: Ping, WhoIs, etc](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_info#group_383) – which a.o. mentions [Ping & DNS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ulfdittmer.android.ping), an app that even displays a graphical analysis of your "`ping` run": ([Screenshot](http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/M16ER34OuvQq_0gbtDF7DfDahHCouKsUJ6dGA9ehbUJtRBbNBe7lMSwxRL6lVQ1493C3J2uHmch6mNvTYd5efV0)).

Comment: Huh. Can I just write some kind of batch script in terminal?